# permission and user/group of a program executed through a script

Tags: permissions, users, executable

I am curious, in the following scenario, what kind of permission does a shell script or Java program has (owner/group/other)?

There is a script called `run.sh`, and it in turn calls a Java program `a.java`. The script and the java is owned by user A and have `-rwxrw-r--` permissions. When they were run by user A, which permission group do they belong to? Do they get the permission from user A as a owner?

And there is another user B, who is in the same group with user A. He execute `run.sh` and in turn calls the Java program. Now what permission group do they belong to? Do they get the permission from user B as a group?

Maybe the program will try to write on a directory `/common/abc` which have a permission of `drwxrw-r--`, if the program have a permission of "other", it will fail.

A point to notice, is that they both use the expression `sh run.sh` to run the script, so they don't need the execute permission. Does it only require the read permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All processes start executing as the same user and group(s) as the process that call them, unless they are called through a [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or setgid executable, i.e. one that has `rws` or `r-s` or `-ws` or `--s` in its permissions. The permission bits other than the `s` bit are irrelevant. The owner of the executable only matter if the script is setuid (i.e. has the `s` bit set in the user column), and the owning group only matters if the script is setgid (i.e. has the `s` bit set in the group column.

Therefore, in the scenario you describe, when user A runs the script, the script and the Java program are both executed as user A, and as whatever group(s) A belongs to. When they are executed by user B, they are executed as user B and as whatever group(s) user B belongs to.

Running a native executable requires execution permission and nothing more. Running a script (a program starting with `#!`) requires both execution permission (to start the execution, before the `#!` mechanism takes over) and read permission (for the interpreter to read the script). If you invoke the interpreter explicitly, the script doesn't need to be executable: as far as the system is concerned, it's just another data file.